# Add Content To Dialog Box DOJO

Tags: css, dojo, dialog

writing an app for opensocial brings up the following problem:

I create a dialog box (css is tundra)

myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({ 
      title: "My Dialog", 
      content: "test content", 
      style: "width: 300px" 
  });

How can I change the properties  "overflow"  and /or "height" of the

"dijitDialogPaneContent"

contained in myDialog after creating this object?

Thank you 
Subin

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches you can use, depending on how generic the solution should be.

### Apply to all dialogs

If you want to apply the same style to all dialogs, you can "extend" a theme, for example, normally you would use the tundra theme like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="location/to/tundra.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="tundra">
        <!-- Your content comes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're going to apply it to all dialogs, you could do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="location/to/tundra.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="tundra custom">
        <!-- Your content comes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

And then write a custom stylesheet like this:

```css
.custom .dijitDialogPaneContent {
    overflow: hidden; /** Custom styles */
}
```

This will guarantee that it will override the general Tundra style for all dialogs. If you don't use a class like `.custom`, you cannot override the Tundra stylesheet because `.tundra .dijitDialogPaneContent` will be more specific (which means it has a higher priority).

Of course, you could write `.tundra .dijitDialogPaneContent` in your custom stylesheet as well.

---

### Apply to a single dialog through stylesheet

If you want to apply it to a single dialog, then give an ID to the dialog, for example:

```
myDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
    title: "My Dialog",
    content: "test content",
    style: "width: 300px",
    id: "myDialogId"
});
```

Then you could write a stylesheet like this:

```css
#myDialogId .dijitDialogPaneContent {
    overflow: hidden; /** Custom styles */
}
```

---

### Apply to a single dialog (using JavaScript)

Seperate stylesheets may improve readability because you seperate logic from design. If you don't need the seperate stylesheet you could do something like this:

```
require([ "dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom" ], function(query) {
    // Your code
    query(".dijitDialogPaneContent", myDialog.domNode).style("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

This will use the [`domNode`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/Dialog#1_9dijit_Dialog_domNode) property of the dialog to query the content pane and then apply the style.

---

### Apply to multiple dialogs

If you want to apply the same style to multiple dialogs (but not all dialogs), then your best approach would be to create a custom dialog by extending the default dialog. Considering the length of my answer atm I'm not going to explain that into detail, but I recommend reading guides about [writing your own widget](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/quickstart/writingWidgets.html).

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri M for the quick reply. However my problem is I have a DOjo specific "DOJO.html" like this

Comment: function openDIV(id, dialogID) {
 var htmlContent = $(id).innerHTML;
 top.dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
 if(modal!=null) {
  modal.destroy();
  modal=null;
 }  
 modal = new top.dijit.Dialog({
  id: dialogID , 
  autofocus: false ,
  content: htmlContent
 });
 modal.show();  
}

Comment: css for the same is                                                                            .nihilo .dijitDialog .dijitDialogPaneContent {
 background: #ffffff;
 border:none;
 border-top: 1px solid #d3d3d3; /* w/out this, an <h1> on the top line causes a gap between the .content and .label */
 padding:10px;
 overflow-x:hidden !important;
 overflow-y:auto !important;
 width:520px; 

} I want to remove the bottom scroll bar from my DIV and I am using overflow-x: hidden; and overflow-y:scroll. The changes are working fine when I do F12 and change but css changes are not reflecting in code

Comment: @subin can you add this to your question please? It's really hard to read using the comment section :) And could you also explain me what you mean with "working fine when I do F12 and change but css changes are not reflecting in code".